# google calendar api & php - import event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a php calendar and ALSO want to add my events to my google calendar. Anybody can add events. I don't know if I'm working into the right direction, but this is what i have so far => and where I am stuck :)

- I downloaded google-api-php-client
- created a project in code.google.com/apis/console
- added client id, secret, redirect url and developer key to calendar/simple.php. (was not sure if the developer key should be my API key though)
- uploaded the folder to my server
- accessed simple.php and clicked "Connect Me!"

And that's where the problems start:

1. I don't want this "allow access" page
2. when and where will I be able to add my events. On the redirect url page or on simple.php
3. If the add-event code should be added on simple.php, what is the redirectURL for?

Any help/advice would be great!